# Storing value in a separate matrix using Python

Tags: python, numpy

How do I store value in a new matrix, `T1` with the given criterion? All the outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np

P1 = np.array([[0.04, 0.55, 0.16, 0.39, 0.51],
       [0.23, 0.85, 0.73, 0.53, 0.11],
       [0.43, 0.26, 0.1 , 0.06, 0.88],
       [0.95, 0.27, 0.61, 0.  , 0.17],
       [0.01, 0.72, 0.87, 0.14, 0.06]])

P2=0.1

T=P1[0,:]
T1=P2>T
print(T1)
```

Current output:

```
[ True False False False False]
```

Desired output:

```
T1=array([[0.04]])
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the reasoning behind your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change this:

```py
T1=P2>T
print(T1)
```

To this:

```py
T1=T[P2>T]
print(T1)
```

Note that, this results in printing the following:

```
[0.04]
```

If you are interested in having a matrix, try changing the `print(T1)` to `print([T1])`

Comment: But it is not generating an array. The output I get is ```[0.04]```.

Comment: @Abcdefgh I mentioned that too. The T1 is an array, not a matrix. If you are interested in getting a matrix, you should use `[T1]` instead of `T1`.